# square root of boost units scaled_unit

Tags: c++, boost

I use `boost::units` to handle units in a project.

I have created a scaled unit to store micro meters:

```
using namespace boost::units;
typedef make_scaled_unit<si::length,
                         scale<10, static_rational<-6> > >::type micro_meter_unit;
```

Everything works as expected:

```
quantity<si::length, double> some_meter = 10 * si::meter;
quantity<micro_meter_unit, double> some_mu_meter = 
  static_cast<quantity<micro_meter_unit, double>>(some_meter);

std::cout << "some_meter^2 = " << some_meter * some_meter;  // outputs 100 m^2
std::cout << "some_mu_meter^2 = " << some_mu_meter * some_mu_meter; // outputs 1e+014 p(m^2)
```

Yet the square root operations is not compiled:

```
std::cout << "sqrt(some_meter) = " << sqrt(some_meter); // outputs 3.16228 m^(1/2)
std::cout << "sqrt(some_mu_meter) = " << sqrt(some_mu_meter); //error here
// 'value' : is not a member of 'boost::units::scale_dim_tag'
// ...
// see reference to class template instantiation 
// 'boost::units::root_typeof_helper<X,Y>' being compiled
//with
//[
//  X=boost::units::quantity<pds::ssp::micro_meter_unit,double>,
//  Y=boost::units::static_rational<2>
//]
```

How can I define scaled unit in a proper way to perform square root and other operations?

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example with all the includes and `main`? I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out specifically which units includes you're using just to get your sample code to compile.

Comment: @MarkB Here is list of include files:
`#include <iostream>
 #include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
 #include <boost/units/make_scaled_unit.hpp>
 #include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
 #include <boost/units/cmath.hpp>
 #include <boost/units/io.hpp>`

All code provided can be placed inside `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at it a bit, I think this is a bug.

The documentation suggests the motivation for make_scaled_unit was for the prefixes in system/si/prefixes.hpp

For example:

```
BOOST_UNITS_METRIC_PREFIX(-9, nano);
BOOST_UNITS_METRIC_PREFIX(-6, micro);
BOOST_UNITS_METRIC_PREFIX(-3, milli);

//! The define uses a dimensionless unit to make a scale unit
#define BOOST_UNITS_METRIC_PREFIX(exponent, name)                                                       \
typedef make_scaled_unit<dimensionless, scale<10, static_rational<exponent> > >::type name ## _type;\
BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(name, name ## _type)
```

These are then used like so:

```
quantity<si::length, double> mu_meter( 1.0 * si::micro * si::meter );
```

The idea is that you convert the input into the length type of the underlying system, and then work with those quantities and only worry about conversion when you need to output.

It seems probable that using such scaled units in other ways might have been missed in the library's test coverage. You should post this to the boost trac:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/

Comment: Also, I would advise to consider avoiding explicitly scaled units. What benefit is there to having an explicit type for micro-meter quatities when you can just use quantity<si::length> (and scale on the outputs if needed)?

Comment: Thanks. It comes from requirements. I need to implement algorithms which work with scaled units. Of course I can do scaling manually but it is more convenient to have scaled units.

Comment: It seems like this is actually a bug. After reading motivation for make_scaled_unit I would expect the following code to work:

`quantity<si::length, double> mu_meter(sqrt(1.0 * si::micro * si::meter * si::meter));` Yet it does not work

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's what Steven intended (that it not work.) In the documentation, there is the nanosecond example that he gives. That doesn't work either. It's definitely a bug.

Comment: The ticket svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10270 contains a workaround for this issue